# Solve $\frac {dy}{dx} + y\tan x=y^3 \sec x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve 
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}+y\tan x= y^3 \sec x$$

My Attempt:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} + y\tan x= y^3 \sec x$$
Dividing both sides $y^3$, 
$$y^{-3} \dfrac {dy}{dx} + y^{-2} \tan x= \sec x$$
Put $y^{-2} = z$
$$(-2)y^{-2} \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac {dz}{dx}$$
$$y^{-3} \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac {-1}{2} \dfrac {dz}{dx}$$
Then,
$$-\dfrac {1}{2} \dfrac {dz}{dx} + z.\tan x= \sec x$$
$$-\dfrac {dz}{dx} + (2\tan x) z =2\sec x$$

Comment: As it pertains to the post; do you have any specific question? Perhaps how to handle the last line?

Comment: The last equation (if correct, I didn't check it) is linear. Why not using standard techniques (integrating factor for example) to solve it?

Comment: The last line looks familiar as @Taladris points out, doesn't it? Hint- [Bernoulli's Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{y'}{y^3}+\frac{\tan x}{y^2}=\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$ z'-2z\tan x=-\frac{2}{\cos x}$$
The integrating factor would be now:
$$e^{-2\int \tan x}dx=e^{\ln(\cos^2 x)+C}$$
So multiply both sides by $\cos^2 x$
$$(z\cos^2 x)'=-2\cos x\Rightarrow z\cos^2 x=-2\sin x+C$$
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2 x}{-2\sin x+C}}$$